# Is it an offensive stereotype that Jews tend to stick together?

Tags: current-events

I thought maybe this belonged on the Academia Stack Exchange, but then I thought I should ask the people directly, as I assume the highly ranked people on here are either Jewish or very familiar with Jews. And, I hope this question isn't offensive asking in and of itself. I've had this question ever since I was a kid, but the couple times I met a Jewish person (at least, that they informed me of) I was too scared to ask as I didn't want to offend anyone. Then, I saw an [Anti-Defamation League poll](https://www.adl.org/resources/report/antisemitic-attitudes-usa-guide-adls-latest-poll) saying that X percent of Americans hold one or more offensive stereotypes about Jews, and one of those offensive stereotypes listed is that "Jews stick together more than other Americans." And, this confuses me, because, to me, this sounds like a positive stereotype. Like Asians being good with computers or black guys having large penes. Perhaps it will make sense if I explain how I encountered this anti-semitic trope.

The first two times I encountered this trope, as a kid, was by two black women, lamenting the state of the black community, and saying they needed to emulate the Jews more; i.e. they need to look out for one another more. And, one of these women was in Minneapolis, MN while the other was in Cocoa, FL. One I overheard, the other said it to a group of students, though I can't really remember much about the context. The first time was when I was in 5th grade, the second was 4 years later in 8th grade (I was held back because, I got expelled; long irrelevant story). It was in opposite parts of the country, so I know this belief is not unheard of.

I never thought about it after the first time, because like I said, I only ever had the opportunity to talk to 2 professed Jews. Then, when I heard it the second in FL, it just kind of pinged in my head that I heard this before. Then, as an adult, when I was in the Army, I heard it again, though I don't remember much about the context. By this time, I was in contact with no professed Jew (by professed, I should clarify; I am sure I came into contact with lots of Jews in my life, but "What is your religion" is not a topic that comes up much). So, the question of what they thought about this trope lingered. Finally, I saw the poll not long ago and the question festered.

The reason I felt the need to explain WHY I have had this question is because I have noticed that questions dealing with Jews on various Stacks (particularly History, though some others as well) tend to be sensitive, and I want to show that I am not trying to spread lies. That being said, it does appear that Jews tend to stick together more than most Americans. Again, I am not sure that is a bad thing. For example, most Jews support Israel (though it could also be said that [*most Americans* support Israel](https://news.gallup.com/poll/390737/americans-pro-israel-though-palestinians-gain-support.aspx#:%7E:text=Israel%20Maintains%20High%20Favorable%20Rating&text=Seventy%2Done%20percent%20of%20U.S.,opinion%20of%20the%20Palestinian%20Authority.)). Also, there are a disparate number of Jews in positions of high authority (though I believe this is explained by Judaism' historical dependence on literacy, and later encouragement of higher education). Then, I read something a long time ago, the specifics of which I forget. But it basically went that Ashkenazi (could be hasidic or other type of Jew, I will not pretend to know the difference) Jews had raised their average IQ points some absurd number over some seemingly short period of time. Regardless of how questionable that "stat" is, there is no denying Ashkenazi Jews have a higher than average IQ. I even found a pretty plausible explanation of how this occurred during the Middle Ages ([Natural history of Ashkenazi intelligence](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16867211/#:%7E:text=Ashkenazi%20literacy%2C%20economic%20specialization%2C%20and,intelligence%20but%20not%20spatial%20ability.))

So my question is, what do Jews think about this trope? Is it offensive? Is it true/untrue? Specifically, it would be interesting to see a survey of Jews to see what they think about this.

Now, it did occur to me while writing this that, if taken to the extreme, the trope becomes harmful. Like, if people start to think that not only do Jews stick together, they do so at the expense of others, this could lead to a kind of "Screw them; they only help themselves; why should we help them?" mentality. So, maybe that is why it is seen as offensive, but my only times encountering it is when people were commending Jewish people. I really would like to receive however long an education on this as anyone is willing to give. Again, I hope I didn't offend anyone with this.

As far as what I have tried to answer this question, I have tried several versions of "Survey on Jewish People" "about anti-Semitic tropes". I got some surveys on Jewish people, such as [a Pew Poll on Jewish Americans](https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2021/05/11/jewish-americans-in-2020/). While it does briefly mention anti-semitic tropes (saying that 30% of Jews experienced an anti-semitic trope in person), it says nothing about specific tropes, other than to give the example of "Jews care too much about money".

I also found the American Jewish Committee's [Survey of American Jewish Millennials](https://www.ajc.org/Jewish-Millennial-Survey-2022/American-Jewish-Millennials), which together with the AJC's [Survey of Israeli Jewish Millennials](https://www.ajc.org/Jewish-Millennial-Survey-2022/Israeli-Jewish-Millennials) had some interesting insights, but nothing about specific anti-semitic tropes. Similarly, Jewish Electorate Institute's [April 2022 National Survey of Jewish Voters](https://www.jewishelectorateinstitute.org/2022-national-survey-of-jewish-voters/), provided some uplifting (from my perspective at least) views, but again, nothing on specific tropes. I could go on like this for several different surveys, but none of them reveal anything about this specific trope. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Hey, appreciate your politeness and sensitivity throughout your question. (You should shorten it though, maybe just keeping the paragraph starting with "Now it did occur to me...". It's clear you put a lot of thought into this though, and that care is not lost on anyone. )

Comment: Many minority groups have a sense of community due to shared experiences/origins. This tends to also be true of people who are affiliated with a Jewish community, and especially religious Jews due to a biblical duty to assist one's brethren, but it could be offensive to unfairly single out Jews for criticism or overgeneralize about anyone who is Jewish ("His name is Goldstein, so there's no way he would offer the job to a Gentile. You know how clannish the Jews are!").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good question. No I am not offended, but it is hard to offend me.

I see two types of stereotypes:

**1).** Untrue ones, usually an incident leaves an impression and that is applied to the group and back to other individuals. (ie: untrue even to the group, but certainly to the other individuals).

**2).** Ones that are statistically true about the group.

I personally think that generalities applied to an individual whether positive or negative are "stereotypes" ie: options 1 and 2. In that sense they are not "true" to the individual.

However, type 2, stereotypes that are documented to be generally true might have some useful information about the group or there situation etc.... It likely has some useful applicable knowledge. For example certain genetic illnesses affect European Jews, a true stereotype of the group, but not necessarily true of any individual or even the majority, but enough of a minority to be more common then the general population.

So although it is a "stereotype" that Jews stick together, I do think it has some truth in general (ie: type 2). Though many Jews are sometimes the Jewish people's worst enemy, so certainly not always true.

I actually think that usually when one Jew is on trial, we all feel that we are all on trial, and in fact usually that is what would happen. One Jew would be accused and all Jews in the city would be attacked even if that individual went to trial and received a punishment. Similarly in Israel one Jew does something wrong, he is brought to court and punished, but even still it is reported that all Jewish people are somehow evil.

I also personally think of other Jewish people as extended family, but with so few Jews in the world, that might not be far off.

I would presume most groups who form around a central idea/principle do feel a bond and unity though. It is certainly sad if a person feels they are part of a group where no one cares about each other.

Is it a trope? Probably in the sense that it has been used in the past many times to attack the Jews. For example that the Germans claimed Jews didn't fight for them in WW1, even though they did, or that they betrayed Germany even though they didn't etc.... But that being said it can be used as a trope, it can be used as a stereotype, and it can be used different ways.

Did that help?

Comment: That did help. Thank you so much. I am glad you got this in before it was closed.

Comment: Happy I got in quick there too lol. Seemed about Judaism, maybe just a little rewording here or there if you try again. I guess they want people to focus more on the religion. Good question tho.

Comment: I don't think I will try again. You and the other answer really answered it anyways. Basically, it's a positive and true stereotype that has been taken to the extreme by enemies of Jews to prosecute them, and I understand why now. It all makes sense. It's one of those disappointing things to discover. You're like "Ahh I get it." Which is immediately followed by, "people suck." lol

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, this Jew is proud to say that we stick together.

This is [a good example](https://www.google.com/amp/s/collive.com/shliachs-ploy-to-sneak-in-kosher-food-for-stranded-passengers/amp/). A local religious Jewish couple bought plane tickets to be able to bring food to other Jewish passengers who were stranded in the airport without kosher food.

Of course, one off events aren't the half of it. Jewish-run support programs include [Hatzalah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatzalah), [Shomrim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shomrim_(neighborhood_watch_group)), [Chaverim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaverim), [various Gemach programs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemach), and much more.

It's worth checking out all of these links.

It should be noted that all of these will help non Jews if they call, with the possible exception of Gemach. They are Jewish in the sense that they mainly recruit Jews to help, have an ethical board that consists of Rabbis, and advertise only in the Jewish community.

The idea of helping each other out comes not only from a sense of familial bond, but also from religious values which emphasize it.

So in short, I for one don't find the trope offensive at all. Although it is true that this trope is sometimes used to imply that a certain amount of Jewish favoritism makes its way into hiring decisions, which can unfairly prevent someone qualified from being hired, that criticism ... is not entirely unfair. It isn't hateful per se because it's true sometimes. That said, it's not like Jews will find a Jewish owned company, say they are Jewish and expect to be hired. I've been rejected from Jewish businesses more times than I can count because someone else was more qualified, just like anybody else.